# Setting bash environment within external call

Tags: external-calls

I would like to run external command from *Mathematica*. For this I need to have bash environment configured via reading the content of `${HOME}/.bashrc` file. When I execute the following code in *Mathematica* notebook

```
ReadList["!echo $PATH", String]
```

the content of `PATH` variable is not set as it is in `${HOME}/.bashrc`. The same happens when I explicitly load bash configuration file

```
ReadList["!source ${HOME}/.bashrc; echo $PATH", String]
```

(strictly speaking the above command makes no effect!). So the question is: is it possible to load the configuration stored in `.bashrc` file in *Mathematica* external call under the Linux system (of course without explicitly setting e.g. mentioned `PATH` variable is not a solution for me)?

Comment: `try ReadList["!printenv",String]`  start by figuring aout what shell is running and what environment is avaialable.

Comment: Why not use `Run`?

Comment: Played with this a bit: you can reveal the actual shell with this: `Readlist["!/bin/ps -p $$"]` -- In my case I've got the bourne shell /bin/sh. printenv *incorrectly* shows the SHELL variable inherited from the shell used to invoke mathematica.   So.. make shure your bashrc doesnt do anything incompatable with plain /bin/sh ..

Comment: I don't understand the question. `ReadList["!echo $PATH", String]` gives me `{"/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"}` which is expected since it did not read the contents of my bashrc file. If I do `ReadList["!source $HOME/.bash_profile; echo $PATH", String]` then I get all of the path that I have set up in there.

Comment: As I have stated in the question `ReadList["!source $HOME/.bashrc; echo $PATH", String]` does not take any effect for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me is to start the `Mathematica` form a terminal, instead of Gnome launcher. Then the bash environment, when `ReadList` is executed, will be inherited from the shell itself.